# open and closed quote marks in regex [ ]

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

I have text which I need to extract using elisp regex which contains the opening and closing quote marks :- ” and ”  (not standard " char)

eg the text looks like this:

```
name\tmy-name\t\t
value\ttext here is what I need “inside quotes” text text text\t\t
otherattrib\tvala\t\t
otherattrib2\tvalb\t\t
```

There are real tabs in the buffer - I use \t to show them above.

I need to grab the text after value\t and before the next tab.  Here is my elisp function below.

```
(defun find-text()
  (interactive) 
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (when (re-search-forward "value\t\\([a-zA-Z0-9- ]+\\)")
    (goto-char (point-max))
    (insert "\n\n\ndefault=")
    (insert (match-string 1))))
```

This doesn't quite work due to the quotes.  Can I enter the quotes in the [ ]?

Comment: Obviously the accepted answer is better, but FYI there's nothing preventing you from putting `"` in the character alternation. You simply have to escape it with a backslash: `\"` (which is escaping it for the string read syntax, rather than for the regex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\\([a-zA-Z0-9- ]+\\)
```

How about replacing this with the simpler:

```
\\([^\t]+\\)
```

Unless you want to restrict the characters there, just allow any non-tab character.

Comment: I must be tired :)  Thanks.